# How to send Book data Express.js

Tags: jquery, express

we are working on this project and we need to send the information from the controllers file to book the appointment, could anyone help me to understand where is the error?

```
pool
    .query(
      `SELECT available_instructor.id, available_instructor.instructor_id, available_instructor.day_id, day.name, available_instructor.time FROM available_instructor
      JOIN instructor ON instructor.id = available_instructor.instructor_id
      JOIN day ON day.id = available_instructor.day_id
      WHERE available_instructor.instructor_id = '${req.query.availableInstructor}';`
    )
    .then((result) => result.rows)
    .then((availableInstructor) => {
      const availableScheduleObj = {};
      availableInstructor.forEach((element) => {
        availableScheduleObj[element.instructor.id] = {
          id: element.instructor.id,
          name: element.instructor.name,
          avatar: element.instructor,
          avatar,
        };
        if (element.instructor) {
          availableScheduleObj[element.instructor.day].instructor = {
            id: element.day.id,
            name: element.day.name,
          };
        }
      });
      res.json(availableInstructor);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log("err", err))
    .finally(() => pool.end());
};
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: err error: invalid input syntax for type integer: "undefined"